# Change html code in php when I have many same php files

Tags: javascript, php

I have question if is it even possible.

I have contact.php home.php and porfolio.php .
In every single site I have exacly same header (include "header.php") and only what I need is change one h1. I mean on every site have different title of h1. Is there any possible way, to change on every site html code differently ?

Like every site have same header.php but every time different h1..

Or should I make like "one half of code.php" .. CHANGEABLE CONTENT .. "second half of code.php.

Or should I do it in javascript ? like onload function and if site is contact.php then change h1.innerHTML on "".. ?

```
<body>
<?php include "./components/header.php"; ?>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure someone on stackoverflow have answered a similar question but you can do something like

```
<body>
<?php 
   $h1Content = "put your desired h1 content here";
   include "./components/header.php"; 
?>
</body>
```

Then in your header.php, do

```
<h1><?php echo $h1Content ?></h1>
```

You can also use an isset to check or set a default value

```
<h1><?php echo isset($h1Content)? $h1Content : 'Default Value' ?></h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve this easily. All you have to do is to assign header value to an variable and then use that variable in your header file.

```
//header.php file
<h1><?php echo $mainHeader; ?></h1>
```

and then before you inject the header you have to init that value on each site

```
<?php $mainHeader = 'Hello world'; ?>

<body>
<?php include "./components/header.php"; ?>
</body>
```